# What is the difference between int main(int, char**) and int main(int argc, char **argv)

Tags: visual-c++

I have a my main defined as follows

```
int main (int, char **)
{
    // my code goes here
}
```

Here how can I get the passed arguments?

if it is like below

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{    
     // my code goes here    
     // Here I can get list of arguments using argv 
}
```

But I don't know how to get the input args for the first case.

Comment: It's not possible in the first case: these arguments don't have names to reference to them.

Answer (score 2):

Both are the same `main` function. The only difference is that in the first case parameters are not given variable names, so you cannot use them. This is a useful pattern to get rid of compiler warnings for unused variables. In case your program does not evaluate argc and argv your compiler might complain that you do not use them. When you remove the parameter names then the compiler does not complain. Of course if you want to access the parameters you must write the names.

Of course if you don't need a parameter you might also remove it. But `main` (defined by the standard) is a good example of a function where you do not want to remove a parameter. Another example would be a `virtual` function where an override might not need all the parameters.